# Regular expression to avoid control characters

Tags: javascript, regex, apache-flex

I am working on flex and using regExp to check the value entered from UI. I want to ensure that entered value does not have any control characters and will give warning based on that. Since we support many languages, I can't have regex which have all possible positive values, thus I need to use blacklist control characters regular expression. I tried `^[^\x00-\x1F\x7F\u2028\u2029]*$` but it matches successfully if there is any regular character other than control character. I want it should return no match in case even a single control character is present. What should I change in this regular expression?

Will appreciate for the help.

Comment: Control characters are in `[\x01-\x1A]` range. So, try `^[^\x01-\x1A]+$`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html. You can

Comment: Your regex shouldn't match if you feed it a mixed string of conrtrol and non-control characters (it would, if you dropped the anchors).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick (put your negated set in a lookahead followed by a `.` and capture as a whole):

```
^((?=[^\x00-\x1F\x7F\u2028\u2029]).)*$
```

Comment: It does not work for ab• ◘ ○ cd where characters between ab and cd are control characters. I checked it on https://regex101.com/#javascript . It is showing match while it should show no match.